# Python, compare 2 txt files, find unique lines in the 2nd txt file and output to a new txt file

Tags: python, compare

tried a bunch of codes, this is the one that it get's me the last different line, but not all of them. As title says i am trying to find the unique lines from the 2nd txt file and output to a new txt file.

````
list1 = open('C:\\1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
list2 = open('C:\\2.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')

list_difference = []
for item in list2:
  if item not in list1:
    list_difference.append(item)

with open('some_output_file.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    for line in item:
        file_out.write(line)```
````

Comment: Try adding `list1 = open('C:\\1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8').readlines()` to turn the opened files into a list. it should work.

Comment: @Pietro Strangely, it doesn't outputs the different line, only 1 common line is written in the output file, more exactly the last line of the 2nd file. So basically no difference.

Comment: @cambuchi answer should show what I meant

Comment: @Pietro thank you too for your fast reply. There is a more faster way to do it? the files have more than 2kk lines each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faster solution, turn the lists into sets:

```
list1 = open("file1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()
list2 = open("file2.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
print(f"len set1 {len(set1)}")
print(f"len set2 {len(set2)}")

# free the memory used by the lists
del list1
del list2

set_diff = set()
for item in set2:
    if item not in set1:
        set_diff.add(item)

print(f"len set_diff {len(set_diff)}")
print(set_diff)
```

The check `item in set` runs in constant O(1) time, while for a list is O(n).

Cheers!

Comment: And i should replace the last 2 print lines with ```open('some_output_file.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    for line in list_difference:
        file_out.write(line)```

Comment: Also i should delete the first 2 print lines right? i don't wanna print anything on screen

Comment: Wow, instant results with this code! thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = open('C:\\1.txt','r',encoding='utf-8').readlines()
list2 = open('C:\\2.txt','r',encoding='utf-8').readlines()
# .readlines() returns a list of each line in the file.

list_difference = []
for item in list2:
  if item not in list1:
    list_difference.append(item)

with open('some_output_file.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as file_out:
    for line in list_difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```

This outputs each line of the text file into their appropriate list. Then writes those unique lines to `'some_output_file.txt'`.

Comment: There is a more faster way to do it? the files have more than 2kk lines each

Comment: how can i select both answers as correct?

Comment: You can only select one answer as correct, but you can vote up the answers on the left.